# Node.js hanging when submitting form with jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, express

When I submit a form node.js hangs but it save to mongodb. Please advice on what I do wrong, quite new to node.

### index.js

```
router.post('/add-to-cart/:id', cartController.checkCart, cartController.createCart);
```

### cartController

```
exports.checkCart = async (req, res, next) => {

    const cart = await Cart.findOne({"owner": req.params.id});

    if (!cart){             
       return next();            
    }

    else{
        res.json(req.body);
    };

};   

exports.createCart = async (req, res) => {

    const createCart = new Cart({

        owner: req.params.id,
        status: 'open',
        products: {
            _id: req.body._id,
            quantity: req.body.quantity,
            price: req.body.price
        }
    });

    const newCart = await createCart.save();
};
```

### JQuery

```
$(".submit").click(function(event){   

  $(".form").submit(req.body); 
  $(this).attr("class", "submit btn btn-success"); 
  event.preventDefault();                                                                                           
});
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with jQuery by the way

Answer (score 0):

`exports.createCart` needs to state that it's finished. You should either add the `next` function argument and call it at the end with `next()`, or return something using `res.json()`, `res.end()`, `res.send()`, etc.

Without either of those options, it will hang indefinitely. The way you've done it in the first function is correct; just apply the same thing to the second.

Comment: Thank you, however it will go to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Your second middleware does not have a `next` callback specified. Unfortunately, although node 8 brings us async functions, express still uses the callback pattern. So if nothing ends the response in your `createCart` middleware or calls `next`, the request/response will not complete.

Try something like this in `createCart`:

```
exports.createCart = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const createCart = new Cart({
      owner: req.params.id,
      status: 'open',
      products: {
        _id: req.body._id,
        quantity: req.body.quantity,
        price: req.body.price
      }
    });

    const newCart = await createCart.save();
    res.json(newCart);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: I will try this